# Assign same value to all elements in the same cluster

Tags: r

let's say I have the following table:

```
Text ID Prior ID
Text1 1   1
Text2  1   2 
Text3  1   3
Text4  2   4
```

My goal: For all same IDs in the dataset, assign the same Text value. For example, in this case I'd like to change Text2 and Text3 to Text1, because the values in ID column are the same as the value in Prior ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
# Original table should be named d
setDT(d)

res <- merge(d, d[ID == `Prior ID`], "ID", all.x = TRUE)[is.na(Text.y), Text.y := Text.x]
res <- res[, .(Text = Text.y, ID, `Prior ID` = `Prior ID.x`)]

res
    Text ID Prior ID
1: Text1  1        1
2: Text1  1        2
3: Text1  1        3
4: Text4  2        4
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I cannot reproduce the example - I always end up with the same results in the Text column as in the initial table.

Comment: Post `head(res)` after `merge`

Comment: Thanks a lot! There was a mismatch between the column names, should have double checked.